# Facing difficulty to transfer a file from one server to another using TCL

Tags: ftp, tcl, expect

I am trying to transfer a file from one server to a remote server with the help of a TCL script.
But my script stops after the message "200 Port set okay" and continues to rum from the below telnet session.

I have checked the destination location, my file is not transferred.

Please suggest what can I do or where I am wrong

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh
#!/usr/bin/expect

package require Expect

set p "mm155_005.006.010.200_bt.fw"

#**************************************************************\
                FILE TRANSFER TO REMOTE SERVER                  \
***************************************************************
spawn ftp 10.87.121.26
expect "User (10.87.121.26:(none)):"
send "user\r"
expect "Password:"
send "pswd\r"

expect "ftp>"
send "cd FW\r"
expect "ftp>"
send "ha\r"
expect "ftp>"
send "bi\r"
expect "ftp>"

send "mput \"$p\"\r"
expect "mput $p? "
send "yes\r"
expect "ftp>"
send "ls\r"


#**************************************************************\
                RUNNING THE TRANSFERED FILE                     \
***************************************************************

spawn telnet 10.87.121.26
expect "Login: "
send "user\r"
expect "password: "
send "pswd\r"

expect "*? > "
send "cd FW\r"

expect "*? > "
send "burnboot 30 5.6(10.200)\r"
```

### Output

```
spawn ftp 10.87.121.26
Connected to 10.87.121.26.
220 VxWorks FTP server (VxWorks VxWorks5.4.2) ready.
Name (10.87.121.26:vkumar): user
331 Password required
Password:
230 User logged in
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> cd FW
250 Changed directory to "C:/FW"
ftp> ha
Hash mark printing on (1024 bytes/hash mark).
ftp> bi
200 Type set to I, binary mode
ftp> mput "mm155_005.006.010.200_bt.fw"
mput mm155_005.006.010.200_bt.fw? yes
200 Port set okay                         \ I am unable to see hash progress bar after this line
spawn telnet 10.87.121.26
Trying 10.87.121.26...
Connected to 10.87.121.26.
Escape character is '^]'.

Login: user
password: 

node84.7.PXM.a > cd FW

node84.7.PXM.a > bash-2.05b$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script as reported is unlikely to produce exactly that output; there is nothing from the `ls` done after the `mput`. However, if the `mput` is hanging the most likely problem is that there is a [firewall issue](http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html); FTP uses multiple sockets to do file transfers (which is why FTP is such a pain when it comes to overall firewall management). In particular, it has a command channel (the socket which you communicate with the FTP server over) and a separate data channel per file (and also with the output of some remote commands, such as `ls`); that's what that `Port set okay` is about. This is not firewall-friendly, and it's easy to misconfigure firewalls in this area (especially when there is NAT also in place).

You might (i.e., *try this first*) want to use passive mode instead, as that reduces the complexity at the firewall level. Try issuing a `passive` before the `mput` (just as you currently issue a `bi`nary).

Comment: i have tried passive but it prompts me that it is invalid command

Comment: @user1412256: Ugh! The problem is playing guessing games as to which version of the `ftp` client you've got. Go with Glenn's answer then.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of rolling your own solution in Expect (I also did this about 9 years ago), use the FTP module from tcllib -- it's already battle-hardened.

http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/ftp.html

Comment: FTP package is not available. according to you my script will not work? as you said you have tried this earlier also

Comment: It's pure Tcl, so you should be able to [just download it](http://tcllib.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tcllib/tcllib/modules/ftp/ftp.tcl?revision=1.50&content-type=text%2Fplain) and use it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bash script I wrote with a similar function;

You should be able to adapt it to your needs.

Adding a few lines to SSH in and run the script should be quite trivial.

As a side note; why are you using TCL for this?

```
#!/bin/bash

fileName=`ls /home/user/downloads -t1 | head -n1`
latestFile="/home/user/downloads/$fileName"
echo $latestFile
hostname="HOSTNAME"
username="USER"
password="PASS"
ftp -inv $hostname << EOF
quote USER $username
quote PASS $password
cd transfer/jirabackup 
binary
put $latestFile $fileName
quit
```

Comment: You're assuming that the version of VxWorks in use by the questioner has sshd; these embedded systems are often less good in this respect than you might hope. (If they did, scp would be by far the best to ship the file about!)

Comment: Using TCL is our project requirement :)